# Sharing Webkit Transform Data Between Pages

Tags: javascript, animation, webkit, rotation, transform

I have elements with slow rotation on them using:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);}
}
```

...and:

```
-webkit-animation: rotate 10s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
```

...on each element to apply the rotation.

The problem is upon changing page that rotation will start on each element from scratch, I would ideally like it to set the inital value of each element to the value it was on upon leaving the previous page before continuing to rotate.

I am looking at doing this via Javascript but I'm not sure if such a thing is possible. Retrieving the rotational value doesn't seem to be a problem but passing it to the next page does...

Answer (score 2):

you may want to look inside the html5 history api and simply request the new page with an xmlhttprequest and update your dom while manipulating the url.

one thing that comes to mind is: you could read the transform matrix and save it in localstorage and reapply it...

Comment: Nice answer... if localstorage is out for compatibility reasons, you could stick it in a cookie or, my latest favorite, `window.name`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried using sessionstorage and applying the rotation value based on this, which works except when used in conjuction with keyframe animation - which overrides it. I think a better approach is going to be to have the navigation panel, where the rotating element lies, static from the rest of the site... like the facebook navigation menu.